# File write unexpected output

Tags: c, file-io, whitespace

I have made this program which copies the text from a file to another file. 
The result was, original file contents "This is a test"
                new file contents "This is a test"
Which worked, I then commented that part out and tried to make the output look like this.
The result I wanted, original file contents "This is a test"
                     new file contents,

```
"T
h
i
s

i
s

a

t
e
s
t"
```

For some reason the output is diagonal and messed up, I am almost sure it is because the whitespace character is messing it up, so i tried to check for the space, and not move to the next line when it encounters a whitespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("originalfile.txt", "r");
    char buffer[81];
    fgets(buffer, 81, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    //copies the file
    /*
       FILE *fp2 = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
       fputs(buffer, fp2);
       fclose(fp2);
     */

    //copies but moves to next line after each character
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
    int x;
    char z = '\n';
    int a = z;
    printf("%d", z);
    for (x = 0; x < strlen(buffer); x++){
        fputc(buffer[x], fp2);
        int res = fgetc(fp2);
        if(isspace(res) != 0){
            fseek(fp2,81,SEEK_CUR);
        } else {
            printf("yeh it got here");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohan's solution works. I have tested it in my machine, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("originalfile.txt", "r");
    char buffer[81];
    fgets(buffer, 81, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    FILE *fp2 = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < strlen(buffer); x++){
        fputc(buffer[x], fp2);
        fputc('\n', fp2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted it, still not working, do you think there may be something wrong with cygwin. I use it to compile c code. The result in the new file is, "੔੨੩ੳਠ੩ੳਠ੡ਠੴ੥ੳੴਬਠ੉ਠ੡੭ਠੴੲ੹੩੮੧ਠੴ੯ਠ੣੯ੰ੹ਠੴ੨੩ੳਠੴ੸ੴਠੴ੯ਠ੡੮੯ੴ੨੥ੲਠ੦੩੬੥"

Comment: Humm, could be. Try with: gcc -std=c99 file.c

Comment: now the file is just being copied exactly with the same formatting

Comment: Ok Change the line fputc('\n', fp2); to fputc('\n', fp2); fputc('\r', fp2); and see what happens.

Comment: warning:multi-character character constant

Comment: I edited the last comment. Try fputc('\n', fp2); fputc('\r', fp2);

Comment: it compiles fine, but the output is the same. not sure whats going on aye, thanks for helping anyway

Comment: One last thing, try opening newfile.txt in a different editor, like notepad++ or wordpad

Comment: hahaha you figured it out man, good job. yeh I opened it in notepad++, and its formatted correctly pretty much. thanks man. pretty stupid that notepad.exe doesnt format it correctly though

Comment: Ha ha. Damn Windows :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can update for loop as below to put each char on new line:

```
for (x = 0; x < strlen(buffer); x++){
    fputc(buffer[x], fp2);
    fputc('\n', fp2);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work, thanks anyway. The result is even worse because it comes up with unrecognizable chars rather than the badly formatted version of the original text file

Comment: I guess people use fputc and fgetc instead of putc and getc because they don't like their programs to run too fast.